# Best way to run a nightly report on a Rails app running on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, report, cron-task

I have a Rails app I'm running on Heroku.

I'd like to, every midnight, run a few queries on my database (I could do it with ActiveRecord or SQL, not fussy), do some light processing of the results, and send a formatted email with the data (either inline or attached CSV).

What's the best way to do this? Locally I could just schedule a cron job to run a script, with Heroku I'm not sure. I read that heroku has a cron add-on, but couldn't find it, and I'm not sure what functionality is available there anyways. Can I just do a headless attach to a rails console and get the output? Can I do this as a rake task?

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Heroku cronjob has been deprecated. Check out [Heroku Scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler)

Answer (score 3):

The [Heroku Scheduler addon] mentioned is a good way to do the scheduling.

```
class Report
   def self.generate_and_send
      # Your logic here
   end
end

# To run task in Terminal
$ heroku run rails runner Report.generate_and_send

# What to schedule on Heroku Scheduler
  rails runner Report.generate_and_send
```